# Error when editing sources.list while installing RStudio on Chromebook Linux (beta)

Tags: debian, apt, chrome-os, rstudio

I am following [this](http://blog.sellorm.com/2018/12/20/installing-r-and-rstudio-on-a-chromebook/) great guide for installing RStudio on a Chromebook using Linux (beta). I am using a 2017 Samsung Chromebook 3 (XE500C13K). After appending the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with `deb https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian stretch-cran35` I receive the following error when running `sudo apt update` :

```
E: Malformed entry 3 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

What can I do to trouble shoot this?

Comment: It likely should be `stretch-cran35/` - the trailing slash denotes a [trivial repository](https://askubuntu.com/a/880360/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver It should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `/` is missing in your `sources.list`. [@steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) comment:

> It likely should be `stretch-cran35/`

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follows:

```
deb https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian stretch-cran35/
```

Explanation from debian wiki: [Flat Repository Format](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#Flat_Repository_Format)

> A flat repository does not use the `dists` hierarchy of directories, and instead places meta index and indices directly into the archive root (or some part below it) In `sources.list` syntax, a flat repository is specified like this:
>
> ```
> deb uri directory/
> ```
>
> Where `uri` specifies the archive root, and directory specifies the position of the meta index and the indices relative to the archive root. In Flat repositories, the following indices are supported:
>
> - Packages (under the location directory/Packages)
> - Sources (under the location directory/Sources)

Comment: I would like to also add to this answer, you want to make sure to [use a valid mirror](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html) in your `sources.list` entry as well.